# Use of "before" as a clause at the end of a question using the past simple?

Tags: sentence-structure

In the question:

> Did you teach your grandma something before?

Can the "before" clause be placed there or is the question incomplete?

Comment: It's OK. "before" is used as an intransitive preposition in your example.

Answer (score 2):

It's an accepted and correct usage. A similar question was asked before (!!!). Here is the link:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160966/is-it-ok-to-use-before-at-the-end-of-a-sentence

Comment: Note that "before" is used as an intransitive preposition in the OP's example.